# Angular 2 and web apis

Tags: javascript, angular

I m playing with angular 2 for a while and now I wanted to make some fun stuff using web apis like geolocation (using navigator object) and browser Notifications.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

I know how to inject window object inside of my application, but I can't find anything concerning Notification or navigator objects.

[Angular2 - How to inject window into an angular2 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177221/angular2-how-to-inject-window-into-an-angular2-service)

Does anybody knows how can I inject them inside of a component ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You cannot inject them unless you wrap it in some service, and even if you do so you will inject a **service** and not an API. Other than injecting you can simply use the following:

```
yourWindowObject.navigator.geolocation
```

to reach the browser geolocation or any other window property.

Comment: Haven't seen `$window` mentioned in Angular2.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer you are right, edited that. Anyway one can always create a variable called `$window`...

Comment: Sure :D, but I'd say in your question it's quite essential what `$window` points to.