# Angular2 call function in html from Component

Tags: angular

From my angular2 component, I would like to run a function in my html page.

Example:

```
<script> 
   function doAlert(){
      alert("in doAlert");
   }
</script>
```

This is needed as i am integrating my app into a html page for a third party. And i need to update them on events done in the app.

In the below, i manage to do this using window.doAlert(); is there an alternative to using window.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vZtjbATax5yvmwJVWRrJ?p=preview

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more what you actually try to accomplish. From you question I'm not able to figure what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: If you want to use `window` just use it like you actually do. There is nothing special to use `window` in Angular2.

Comment: How are you integrated with the this party library? Does it support a module loader like commonjs? Regarding `window`, this question could perhaps help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177221/angular2-how-to-inject-window-into-an-angular2-service.

Answer (score 0):

i assumed from your question you are stuck on event binding in angualr so try this-

```
<button (click)='demoFun()'> Button </button>

demoFun(){
//your code..//
}
```

here is working example http://plnkr.co/edit/4UPlh9Pn42yM3VPqYvoL?p=preview
for more refer [see here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cheatsheet.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was ever solved for by you.

But I use {{ functionName() }}
and just return back the information i need.