# Angular2 How to scroll to top of window on user interaction

Tags: angular

so i am having hard time to figure out how to scroll page to top of window upon user interaction (like click on item). In AngularJS i could use `$window.scrollTo(0, 0);`
I am not using Angular2 Router so need something like aformentioned `$window`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the javascript window object or refer to this link if you want to do it purely in angular 2([Angular2 - How to inject window into an angular2 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177221/angular2-how-to-inject-window-into-an-angular2-service)):

---

`window.scrollTo(0,0);`

Comment: Thanks. that worked. Not sure why, but at first i tried it it was marked as error by VS Code, but now it works just fine and i did nothing but copy/paste.

Comment: Awesome. Glad to help. :)

Comment: Are there any advantages of injecting the window as in your link over using `window.scrollTo(0,0);`?

Comment: @GeraintAnderson I don't think so....since the OP was referring to $window service, I wanted to give an Angular solution too.

Comment: This made my day! worked like charm.