# Angular 2 DOM manipulation - Scroll window to top

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm very new to angular and I'm only starting to understand how everything works. I have a button that the user clicks, changes some stuff in the page and in mobile I need it to scroll to top so the user can see what has been changed. All works except the scrolling part. This is what I have:

The link that gets clicked:

```
<div (click)="selectColorElement(item)"> {{item.title}}</div>
```

The function it calls inside the component:

```
selectColorElement(selectedColor: AmbientItem){
    /*Unrelated stuff that changes things in the page, I tried commenting all this and no changes*/

    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

I read this question [Angular2 How to scroll to top of window on user interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657819/angular2-how-to-scroll-to-top-of-window-on-user-interaction) but apparently it does nothing for me in this case.

Comment: I think it should work. Did you do anything special with `window` (is it injected)?

Comment: provide the rest code of handler, maybe an issue was there

Comment: As I said, I commented the code before that to assure it wasn't the culprit. I did nothing with window, anywhere really.