# DI Not Working on Safari

Tags: angular

I have found some [fantastic links](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html) for DI explanations in Angular2, but I am still unable to get it working on Safari.  In the code below, it works in Firefox and Chrome, but I still get a `Can't resolve all parameters for ApiService: (Http, ?).` in Safari.  Am I missing something?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { EmitterService } from '../services/emitter.service';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  constructor (
    private http: Http,
    private window: Window
  ) {}
}
```

From what I can tell everything is there, is there a known cross-browser compatibility issue that I am missing? Or maybe a polyfill for safari specifically?

- I have setup the @NgModules to include `HttpModule` as well.

`import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';`

Comment: How do you provide dependencies?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer As of right now I have @NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,

Comment: The `Http` dependency import is not the problem. As you see in the error message, the 2nd parameter `Window` is the problem. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177221/angular2-how-to-inject-window-into-an-angular2-service especially the comment below http://stackoverflow.com/a/35003208/217408

Comment: Ah,I see-- I thought it stopped at the import it couldn't resolve...  So we can't do this now with the @NgModules? 
  providers: [
    Title,
    provide(Window, { useValue: window })
  ],

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/38875374/217408 I don't have a Safari browser available to test it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GünterZöchbauer was 100% correct in that the issue was the formatting of the providers.  It's not provide() in the @NgModule, its now:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    Title,
    { provide: 'Window',  useValue: window }
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

[Angular2 - How to inject window into an angular2 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177221/angular2-how-to-inject-window-into-an-angular2-service/38875374#38875374)