# Angular 2 access window object

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to access the `window` object of the browser with Angular 2. I have seen some solutions on stack overflow but they don't work with NgModules (Angular 2 RC5 version).

I just want to detect the browser (chrome, firefox, safari, opera, IE) and put it as a class in `<body>` tag

Any pointers please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177221/angular2-how-to-inject-window-into-an-angular2-service

Comment: I did try that method and it didn't work. Initiallizing in the constructor gives error.