# Uncaught ReferenceError: PasteFromWord is not defined

Tags: javascript, module, referenceerror

I am trying to incorporate the [PasteFromWord](https://github.com/ihwf/paste-from-word) module into my web app.  I downloaded [the two files](https://github.com/ihwf/paste-from-word/tree/main/lib) and dropped them into my app.  My web app technology doesn't really matter, but for reference it is Java + Tomcat 8.5 + JSF 2.3 + Primefaces 8.0 + p:textEditor (which uses [Quill](https://quilljs.com/) underneath).  The framework has already included jQuery.

I modified `PasteFromWord.js` slightly from the original to `import tools from './tools.js'` instead of `'./tools'` to fix a browser complaint, and added a `console.log` statement.  Here is what `PasteFromWord.js` looks like:

```
import tools from './tools.js'

console.log("Initializing PasteFromWord");

class PasteFromWord {
    constructor(config) {
        this.config = config || {}
    }

    ... rest of class definition omitted ...
}

export default PasteFromWord
```

I put this in the outputted HTML header to load the module:

```
<script type="module">
    import PasteFromWord from '../PasteFromWord.js';
    console.log("imported PasteFromForward=" + PasteFromForward);
</script>
```

Both the log message in the `PasteFromWord.js` and the log message in the `<script>` tag show up in the console demonstrating that it is loading the script and the function is defined.

Farther down in the HTML output, I have this code to actually use it:

```
<script type="javascript">
    $(window).ready(function() {
        console.log("about to create PasteFromWord");
        var paster = new PasteFromWord();
        // more code will go here in the future
    });
</script>
```

The log message prints out, and on the next line, in the browser console **I get the following error** (identical in Firefox and Chrome):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: PasteFromWord is not defined
```

I have searched a lot for causes of `ReferenceError`, but none of the solutions applies.  I believe I have all the bases covered, but obviously something is missing.  Is there something wrong with scope?  Strict mode?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

This answer (inspired by [an answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39383274)) seems to work, but I am not happy with it so I am not marking it as the solution.  Hopefully there is a better answer, or someone who works with JavaScript more regularly than I do can say whether it is an appropriate answer.

The problem appears to be one of scope, where `PasteFromWord` is available inside the initial `<script>` tag that imports the module, but not later.  So the answer is to assign the class definition to be a member of an object that is known in other scopes.

```
<script type="module">
    import PasteFromWord from '../PasteFromWord.js';
    window.PasteFromWord = PasteFromWord;
    console.log("imported PasteFromForward=" + PasteFromForward);
</script>
```

Then, the class can be instantiated by prepending `window.` to the class name:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).ready(function() {
        var paster = new window.PasteFromWord();
        // more code will go here in the future
    });
</script>
```