# On route change view doesn't scroll to top in the new page in angular2

Tags: angular, routes

I have tried `autoscroll="false"` on the `router-outlet` but does't seem to work, is there any default method 
of angular2 for doing the same without using any third party library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Scroll to top on Route Change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601026/angular-2-scroll-to-top-on-route-change)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39601987/5043867

we can subscribe to the route change event and scroll to the top with something in the lines of

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
        if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
            return;
        }
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    });
}
```

Update -

In Angular v6+ there is a new method `scrollPositionRestoration` introduced. for more info read out here

- https://medium.com/@PardeepJain/deep-dive-into-angular-routing-scrolling-to-top-debugging-and-lot-more-a995c08498d3

Comment: I wish there was an easier way - instead of having the code in the UI in one place it is now in the component code

Comment: This is also an easier way I think we have to code once in the main app component

Comment: @Pradeep Jain : This works fine if I change from one route to another however it dosen't scroll to top on param change on same route, I added this service on  this._route.params.subscribe event still it remains at same position

Comment: yes because for the same route this event will not trigger ,so in that case you need to change your logic depending on the changes of params too

Answer (score 8):

#### Until Angular 6

here is a more neat way to do it:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((ev:any) => {
  if (ev instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
});
```

#### From Angular 6.1

You could do this in your router configuration. This is likely to be the norm in future versions as suggested [here](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v6-1-now-available-typescript-2-9-scroll-positioning-and-more-9f1c03007bb6).

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'})
```

Answer (score 4):

Angular lately introduced a new feature, inside angular routing module make changes like below

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'
  })],
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.
It can be used as smooth scroller to precised ID or instant scroller in order to fix top position.

Component that route is driven to:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.commonService.scrollTo('header', BEHAVIOR.auto)
  }
```

Service:

```
  scrollTo(element: string, behavior: BEHAVIOR): void {
    (document.getElementById(element) as HTMLElement).scrollIntoView({behavior: behavior, block: "start", inline: "nearest"});
  }
```

Enum:

```
export enum BEHAVIOR {
  smooth = 'smooth',
  auto = 'auto'
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can refer to **[fragments](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#fragment)** available in **Angular2-router**.

Comment: will you please elaborate your answer bit more, btw thanks for answer :)