# Angular2 How to navigate to certain section of the page identified with an id attribute

Tags: angular, routes, navigation, fragment

How to navigate to certain section of the page identified with an id attribute?

Example:

I need to navigate to "structure" paragraph on my page

```
<div id="info">
  <h3>Info</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>    
<div id="structure">
  <h3>Structure</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

And I have a following navigation structure:

```
<li>
  <ul materialize="collapsible" class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li><a routerLink="policies" class="collapsible-header">Policies</a>
      <div class="collapsible-body">
         <ul>
           <li><a >Info</a></li>
           <li><a >Structure</a></li>
           <li><a >Something Else</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
```

It is my understanding that in Angular1.0 I simply could've navigate to the page section using something like: ui-sref="policies({'#':'structure'})"  or href="#structure"  or ui-sref="policies" href="#structure"...

How can I do it in Angular2? I looked at the Fragment example in the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html): Query Parameters and Fragments section and I am finding they example to be very confusing and a bit overkill for such a potentially simple task

Answer (score 20):

**Angular 2:** I would prefer to go with scrollIntoView() method [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). It would provide smooth scrolling transition effect in the browser. 
**HTML Code**

```html
    <div #info id="info">
        <h3>Info</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div #structure  id="structure">
        <h3>Structure</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>

  <li>
    <ul materialize="collapsible" class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
      <li><a routerLink="policies" class="collapsible-header">Policies</a>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
           <ul>
             <li (click)="infoStruc()"><a >Info</a></li>
             <li (click)="moveToStructure()"><a  >Structure</a></li>
             <li><a >Something Else</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
```

and in the Component.

```ts
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `template.html        `
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('structure') public structure : ElementRef;

    @ViewChild('info') public info : ElementRef;

    public moveToStructure():void {
            this.structure.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end', inline: 'start' });
    }

    public infoStruc():void {
        setImmediate(() => {
            this.info.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end', inline: 'start' });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

I have used a combination of the previous answer once a click is performed in the HTML file:

```
<ul>
   <li><a (click)="internalRoute("routeexample1","info")">Info</a></li>
   <li><a (click)="internalRoute("routeexample2","structure")>Structure</a></li>
   <li><a (click)="internalRoute("routeexample3","something")>Something Else</a </li>
</ul>
```

In the component typescript file (component file) it is necessary to define the corresponding navigation including Router and navigation:

```
constructor(private router:Router) { }
internalRoute(page,dst){
    this.sectionScroll=dst;
    this.router.navigate([page], {fragment: dst});
}
```

With this, the app is able to navigate to the corresponding page but not to the specific section. To go to the defined (desirable) section, it is needed to do the scroll. For that, we initially define a function to do the scroll to specific "id"  ([Scroll Function here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819549/angular2-scroll-to-element-that-has-ngif)):

```
doScroll() {

    if (!this.sectionScroll) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      var elements = document.getElementById(this.sectionScroll);

      elements.scrollIntoView();
    }
    finally{
      this.sectionScroll = null;
    }
  }
```

Finally, we need to capture the navigation event and perform the scroll (modifying the ngInit function) ([Event capturing page Init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601026/angular-2-scroll-to-top-on-route-change)):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
      if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
        return;
      }
      this.doScroll();
      this.sectionScroll= null;
    });
  }
```

It works for me. Hopes help.

Comment: First solution that worked for me. Thanks a lot for trying and combining different solutions. If I could upvote more, I would have

Answer (score 4):

You could add `fragment` attribute for your html link

```
<ul>
   <li><a [routerLink]="['routeexample1']" fragment="info">Info</a></li>
   <li><a [routerLink]="['routeexample2']" fragment="structure">Structure</a></li>
   <li><a [routerLink]="['routeexample3']" fragment="something">Something Else</a></li>
 </ul>
```

To navigate programmatically you could this

```
this.router.navigate( ['routeexample1' ], {fragment: 'structure'});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried both and it's not working.... I am using Angular 2.0.1 if that helps..

Comment: AFAIR there is an open issue about navigating with fragments.

Comment: how to receive the frament inside 'routeexample1'

Comment: It is not a complete answer