# scrollIntoView() doesn't work with application selector

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Does anybody know the proper implementation of scrolling to anchor. This approach doesn't work:
[Angular2 scroll to element that has *ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819549/angular2-scroll-to-element-that-has-ngif?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Here is the template that has references to other components:

```
<app-app1 id="id1"></app-app1>
<app-app2 id="id2"></app-app2>
<app-app3 id="id3" *ngIf="test"></app-app3>
```

By clicking on a button I'd like to scroll to the appropriate section:

```
let elm = document.querySelector("#id1");
if (elm)
  elm.scrollIntoView();
```

The scrollIntoView() is executed but it scroll to wrong place (like to the middle of the section) and doesn't work for app-app3 at all.

Comment: Is `test` true before and after clicking the button?

Comment: In my case it's true when page loads.. and not changed then... *ngIf not really big problem.. first I want it to scroll to the proper place within the app selector

Comment: @JohnGlabb do you have multiple elements with the `id` of `id1` ..

Comment: no.. it's unique.. Consider that the content of each component is really large. I even tried to wrap it into parent <div id="uniqueID"><app-app1.... Then it scrolls to incorrect place

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it this way:
1. Remove "id3" from app selector component:

> ```
>    change: <app-app3 id="id3" *ngIf="test"></app-app3>
>    to:     <app-app3 *ngIf="test"></app-app3>
> ```

2. Put new div inside  component at the very top:

> < div id="id3"> < /div >

3. Change:

> ```
> let elm = document.querySelector("#id3");
> if (elm)
>   elm.scrollIntoView();
> ```

to:

> ```
> let elm = document.getElementById("id3");
> elm.scrollIntoView({behavior: "instant", block: "center", inline: "center"});
> ```