# Angular 11 Directive Questions

Tags: angular, directive

I am trying to understand how Directives work. I am trying to use a Directive to scroll to an alert dialog when it pops up.

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="errorMsg" class="alertContainer" ScrollTo>
  {{ errorMsg }}
</div>
```

ScrollToDirective.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ScrollTo]'
})
export class ScrollToDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) { }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
  }

}
```

I searched Stackoverflow and found this solution [Angular2 scroll to element that has *ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819549/angular2-scroll-to-element-that-has-ngif)

I tried to replicate it and had no luck. Can anyone shed some light as to why the page isn't scrolling?

Comment: Did you add the directive to the declarations array in your module?

Comment: @MikkelChristensen I'm not sure. I read the API from https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

I typed ng generate directive ScrollTo

Comment: Just confirmed "ScrollTo" is declared in my app.module.ts

Comment: Must be something else then, since I tried the code in a stackblitz exactly as you've got it in your question and it worked.

Comment: @MikkelChristensen Thanks for double checking. I'll see if I can figure it out