# Navigate to a certain section of an AngularJS page from a non Angular page

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an angular page that has a structure like below:

```
<div id="topSection">
    top section
</div>

<div id="bottomSection">
    bottom section
</div>
```

From an external page (non angular), I'll need to provide a link to navigate to the `bottomSection` of the page. I looked at `$anchorScroll()` and it only appears to work for links within the same page. Thanks

Comment: I have answered this question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498333/angular2-how-to-navigate-to-certain-section-of-the-page-identified-with-an-id-at/47713962#47713962

Comment: The answer you linked is for Angular 2. I am using AngularJS (v1)

Comment: Adding few lines of javascript code or mentioning it in question could be helpful to others