# angular: how to make link to jump for certain section in the same page

Tags: angular, routes

I want to an anchor link to jump to specific section in the same page using id hashtag. here is my html:

```
<div class="nav-container">
  <ul class="nav text-center">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#account-services">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['//account/'+account.account_id]" fragment="account-about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#account-gallery">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#account-reviews">Reviews</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="account-details">
  <div id="account-services">
    <h1>services</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="account-about">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="account-store">
    <h1>Store</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="account-gallery">
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="account-reviews">
    <h1>Reviews</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

ts component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account-individual',
  templateUrl: './account-individual.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account-individual.component.css']
})
export class AccountIndividualComponent implements OnInit {

  private fragment: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => { this.fragment = fragment; });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    try {
      document.querySelector('#' + this.fragment).scrollIntoView();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you console this.fragment?

Comment: @ShaileshLadumor yes, the result is the `href` attribute value

Comment: The solution to this question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44215585/6293412).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install this package [ng2-page-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-page-scroll)

After that import in your `app.module.ts`

```
    import {Ng2PageScrollModule} from 'ng2-page-scroll';
    
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            /* Other imports here */
            Ng2PageScrollModule
            ]
    })

   export class AppModule {
   }
```

and test in your component html

```
<a pageScroll href="#home">Testing</a>
<div id="home">
```

Comment: Now called ngx-page-scroll https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-page-scroll

Answer (score 16):

Use fragment as you did and assign it to a click event:

in your template

```
<a fragment="account-about" (click)="navigateToSection('account-about')>About</a>

<div id="account-about">...</div>
```

in your component

```
public navigateToSection(section: string) {
      window.location.hash = '';
      window.location.hash = section;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is for Angular 13 where ngx-page-scroll is not working currently.

```
import { ViewportScroller } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {}

public onClick(elementId: string): void { 
  this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(elementId);
}
```

Add upper part in component.ts file. For html file -

```
     <a (click)="onClick('about')" >About</a>
     <div id="about">....</div>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on Angular 13

Comment: It's working in Angular CLI: 17.0.8, Node: 20.9.0, Package Manager: npm 10.1.0, Angular: 16.2.8.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => { 
                      setTimeout(() => {
                            this.scrollTo(fragment);
                        }, 300);
     });
```