# How to navigate to specific sections of a page when using HashLocationStrategy

Tags: html, angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to use anchor tags to navigate to a certain section of a page. I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835140/how-do-i-link-to-part-of-a-page-hash) post and used the suggested solution. Although the solution works, I get this console error:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'helpComp'

where helpComp is the id of div I'm navigating to.

My guess is that the # conflicts with the HashLocationStrategy which I am required to use. Can someone suggest an alternative to using the anchor and # for navigating within the page or other ideas?

I can't share my code but here is the general idea:

```
<a href="#helpComp">Step 1</a>
<p id="helpComp">Contents</p>
```

When I click on Step 1, it takes me to the correct section of the page but the console displays the above error.

Comment: Hi, mate welcome to SO it would be great if you could share your code. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn some details about the expected format of questions on the site.

Comment: I've added a few changes. Does the problem seem clear now?

Comment: Check this [out](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13636)

Comment: So is there no support for page jumps in HashLocationStrategy?

Comment: Well, the open issue about navigating with fragments says that Anyways  I will upvote your question see what other's got to say about this

Comment: This might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48278403/5695162)