# How to link to an anchor on the same page in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am loading a page to a named outlet using "**routerLink**" like this.

```
<a [routerLink]="{outlets: {doc: 'introduction'}}">Introduction</a>
```

I need to jump to an anchor point in the loaded page. Using "routerLink", is there a way?

For example, if I have a sub-section in the page called "setup" and I want this to be navigated to on page load.

```
<a href="introduction">Introduction</a>

Lorem Ipsum is ...

<a href="setup">Setup</a>
```

Comment: why don't u use the good ol' method - #setup id and link as <a href="#setup">Setup</a> ?

Comment: It needs to work with angular routing :) using a named outlet. The link is another sidebar component.

Comment: If you are using ui.router then you will also need to do child routing, but for ngroute you can do it easy by using `#setup` for every route you want in an anchor tag.

Comment: There is a solution in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/44441089/5866606 Hope it helps

Comment: Hi JeffersonSwartz, I've seen that solution, but not exactly what I am looking for. It also doesn't work with my use case as I am rendering markdown to html in my component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular: how to make link to jump for certain section in the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277721/angular-how-to-make-link-to-jump-for-certain-section-in-the-same-page)