# is there any default angular property to scroll into top of the screen in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I am looking for default angular property for scroll into top of the window while route changes apart from using js functions like(window.scroll,el.scrollIntoView).After searching on internet I found some useful properties like ngx-page-scrolll,but it navigated based on creating the html element instance.How can I navigate into top of the window by using any of the angular scroll property?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5 Scroll to top on every Route click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048299/angular-5-scroll-to-top-on-every-route-click)

Answer (score 1):

*Bias note: I'm the creator of the mentioned `ngx-page-scroll` library.*

---

Using the `PageScrollService` that is exported from the module you can trigger scrolls without the need to create HTML Elements.

The following simple example shows, how to create a so called `pageScrollInstance` (an object containing all relevant information to perform a scroll operation) that scrolls to an element with id `top`:

```
 constructor(private pageScrollService: PageScrollService, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {
 }

 public goToHead(): void {
     let pageScrollInstance: PageScrollInstance = PageScrollInstance.simpleInstance(this.document, '#top');
     this.pageScrollService.start(pageScrollInstance);
 };
```

You may just trigger that `goToHead()` to start the scroll animation.

More details and how to set it up can be found in the documentation: https://github.com/Nolanus/ngx-page-scroll#service

Comment: Is there a way to reference a angular dialog as the document? When I use the code right now it grabs the entire document. I would like this functionality inside the dialog only.

Comment: It's possible. Please check the documentation or [this github ticket](https://github.com/Nolanus/ngx-page-scroll/issues/273) and there's also an example in the demo app (tab "nested scrolling"). In case you still have problems, please create a new SO question or github issue.