# How to use scrollPositionRestoration in RouterModule.forchild(); ? How to make the page always scroll at top after page navigation?

Tags: routes, angular7, scrolltop

scrollPositionRestoration : 'top' is not working for RouterModule.forchild()? Is there any solution in angular 7 to make sure that page always scroll top after navigation?

Comment: I have same problem, did you finds any solution for this?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048299/angular-5-scroll-to-top-on-every-route-click?rq=1             I tried this and worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' }),
```

Comment: The question aims for `RouterModule.forChild()` where `scrollPositionRestoration` is not applicable.

Comment: @StarneyBinson please read what his latest comment was on the original post and what worked. my answer is correct.