# Angular 9 scroll to top on route every change

Tags: javascript, angular9

I'm working on a project in which I have a lot of routes and each time I click on a link to go to a specific route the page does not scroll to top automatically which is annoying and not good. Does anyone know how to fix this problem, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 Scroll to top on Route Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601026/angular-2-scroll-to-top-on-route-change)

Comment: No sorry I already tried that.

Comment: I think I found a great answer to this question it's right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048299/angular-5-scroll-to-top-on-every-route-click/48048822)

Comment: Quoting that response, "Since Angular6.1, we can also use { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' } on eagerly loaded modules and it will be applied to all routes"

Comment: Yes that will work too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add the following configuration to the routing module in the extra options:

```
const routes: Routes = [ ... ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

For your interests, the option `scrollPositionRestoration` can be `top` (go to top on every navigation change) or `enabled` (like top, but when going backwards it restores the last position).

More info: https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand scrollPositionRestoration, how does it scroll to top ?

Comment: how to disable smooth scroll and make it snap to top instantly ?

Comment: @Ibrahim Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Jul nope. Tell me if you do.

Comment: I had the same issue (disable smooth scroll) and I had to disable the global css rule `scroll-behavior: smooth;` and apply it only within the pages where I wanted the behaviour instead of within the `html` tag

Comment: is this possible to override   scrollPositionRestoration option for specific router.navigate() ?