# Angular instantly scroll to top from a service

Tags: angular, scroll

How do I instantly (not animated!) scroll to the top in Angular8+ from a service?
window.scrollto(0,0) does not work.

```
$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
   scrollTop: 0
}, 100)
```

Isn't beautiful but works at all at least but the duration value seems to not be allowed to be set to 0 (which would anyway completely lose the purpose of jquery's animate method :) )

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048299/angular-5-scroll-to-top-on-every-route-click/48048822) might help. Also make sure you have no `scroll-behavior: smooth;` in `body`, `html` or the container.

Comment: Aw man this was the problem scroll-behavior: smooth; at least for jquery animate with duration 0. I feel so endlessly stupid. Thank you a lot, a lot, a lot.
Post it as an answer then I'll accept it?

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear it worked for you :) No worries, btw. You can accept @Beller's answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use scrollIntoView like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("box");
element.scrollIntoView();
```

You can add a few optional params

```
element.scrollIntoView(false);
element.scrollIntoView({block: "end"});
element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"});
```

Edit from OP:
Also make sure no `scroll-behavior: smooth;` is active!

Comment: Works like a charm in combination with Harun's comment on my question. Thank you!