# Scroll to top of the HTML page whenever refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am fighting with a small issue for a few hours.

I am working on Angular-9, in the HTML page, I have a very long table(500 rows data). when I going to the bottom of the table and then refresh the page, it will be on the bottom of the page. not scrolling to the top of the page.

but whenever I refresh the page, the page should go to the top of the HTML page(top of the table).

Actually, I have searched a lot of google solutions, but no one is work.

Can u please suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: This heavily depends on your HTML structure and how you display your data. You should add some code, so we can see how it looks like. Also, please provide what "google solutions" you tried that did not work.

Comment: 1.  window.scrollTo(500, 0);

Comment: 2. $(window).scrollTop(position);

Comment: 3. $('document').ready(function() {
   $(window).scrollTop(0);
});

Comment: And the `window` is your scrollable container? Pretty sure you have another container inside that is the scrollable one.

Comment: Just use the ngAfterContentInit lifecycle method and add a document.body.scrollTop = 0;
or a document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0 inside it?

Comment: Pretty sure the document is not his scrollable element, but a `div` or something. You need to call this method on that element.

Comment: Just use the ngAfterContentInit lifecycle method and add a document.body.scrollTop = 0; or a document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0 inside it?             

Not working bro...

Comment: yeah... its is scrollable container. because 500 above rows in that table

Answer (score 0):

Add this in js file.

```
$(this).scrollTop(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a header component you can directly try this, or just make a empty div at the top of the page with id header and paste this in your main function.
Make sure of the ID or it will not work.

```
const header= document.getElementById('#header');
header.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: In HTML:
<div class="row" id="topPage"></div>

In TS file:

ngOnInit(): void {
const header= document.getElementById('#header');
header.scrollIntoView();
}


But not working bro...

Comment: The HTML you provided in your comment suggests a div with ID "topPage". For this you will have to change the TS code as such:  ```const header= document.getElementById('#topPage');
header.scrollIntoView();``` @Siva

Comment: Yeah.  I have changed.. But still not working bro..

Comment: @Siva check this one out https://stackoverflow.com/a/48048822/14547185

Comment: yeah... ur shared linked is working fine... thanks for ur help...

Comment: If it worked please upvote it so that it reaches to more peple thanks! @Siva

Answer (score 0):

On your template, add a template variable to your scrollable container like this:

```
<div #myScrollableContainer>
   <!-- Here is your content that scrolls -->
</div>
```

And on your component get that one with `@ViewChild` and set the scrollTop on that.

```
@Component({ /*...*/ })
export class MyComponent {
   // pass the name of the template variable you picked with # on your template
   @ViewChild('myScrollableContainer') private myContainer:ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

   // Call this when you want to scroll to top
   public scrollToTopOfScrollable():void {
      this.myContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = 0;
   }
}
```