# scrollTop on tab Click Ionic 6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to scrollTop actual view when click on Tab on Ionic 6.
In home I have the tabs ['tab1','tab2','tab3'], for example: I'm in 'tab1' and when I click again on same tab have to scrollTop.

I try with ionViewWillEnter but this works if I enter the view.
How to setup this method?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... do you simply want to scroll to the top of the current screen if someone clicks a tab button? Or do you want scroll to a specific section of a screen when a user clicks a tab button?

Comment: @Super_Simon I want scroll to the top of the current screen clicking tab button.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048299/angular-5-scroll-to-top-on-every-route-click

Comment: This work for every page on my App, but I just wanna for few tabs.