# angular 4.0 slide to top when page is reloaded

Tags: angular

I used this jQuery code and it is working fine. But I want to use the same flow in angular. Is it possible? Can we write for `beforeunload` function in angular?

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can do something like:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    // or window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I need whenever reload the page, then show the page is top by using of angular. Is it possible to write the code in angular?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this like-

```
<div (window:beforeunload)="someMethod()"></div>
```

Or You do like this-

```
@Component({ 
  selector: 'test',
  'template': ''
)}
class TestComponent {
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  someMethod() {
    // You can handle scroll here
  }
}
```

Comment: I need whenever reload the page, then show the page is top by using of angular. Is it possible to write the code in angular?

Comment: Can you explore a bit more, I didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about [Angular - Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

or mayble this [link](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) explaining the lifecycle methods.

```
ngOnInit() {
   window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}
```

You can also see [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39601987/2979938) about your problem. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try this html.

```
<div #list [scrollTop]="list.scrollHeight"></div>
```

In Component define id into html id="scrollId"

```
const element = document.querySelector('#scrollId');
element.scrollIntoView();
```

or

you can use this in TS

```
 window.scrollTo(0 , 0);

 window.scrollTo( 0 , document.body.scrollHeight);// where you can describe the height to scroll to
```

Comment: I need whenever reload the page, then show the page is top by using of angular. Is it possible to write the code in angular?

Comment: i did not understand what you're trying to say

Comment: Hi Abhushek, thanks for the response. My intention is when I am scrolling down a page from top to bottom, say I reached bottom of the page and I clicked/reloaded the page right now as per browser behavior the page points to bottom . But I want to go to top of the page when page gets reloaded.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve using angular 4.0?

Comment: @kanakaraju by default when the page is reloaded it will point towards top of the page all the time and for every instance.