# How to scroll down on ngOnInit in angular?

Tags: angular

I want to scroll down to a section when the page loads in Angular on some condition.

**Please note:** I want to scroll down without clicking on anything(i.e, on `ngOnInit`).

I tried this:
in my **component.html** file

```
<div #sectionSubscribe>
    HTML...
</div>
```

in my component.ts file

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.scrollToSubscribe(sectionSubscribe);
}
scrollToSubscribe($element){
    $element.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'start',
        inline: 'nearest'
    });
}
```

But it doesn't allow me to do so.
Please help

Comment: Did you tried any code? Or searched on internet?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Yes I tried but can't find anything. They all do it by clicking on button which I don't want.

Comment: Then post the tried code so someone will help

Comment: Try this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601026/angular-2-scroll-to-top-on-route-change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@ViewChild("sectionSubscribe", { static: true }) sectionSubscribeDiv: ElementRef;

scrollToSubscribe(){
    this.sectionSubscribeDiv.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" });
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l2ncvr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**