# How to automatically scroll to top of page on Route change - Angular12

Tags: angular, typescript

If I clicked a link at the bottom of the current component, it routes to another one at the same position. How to make it route automatically to the top of the new component?

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601026/angular-2-scroll-to-top-on-route-change