# Changing route not scrolling to the top of the screen on mobile

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried all the answers on this post in order to take the user to the top of the screen when they hit a link and change the route:

[Angular 2 Scroll to top on Route Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601026/angular-2-scroll-to-top-on-route-change)

And they all work when the application is on a web browser, but I cannot make any of those different and right answers work on a mobile device, including the simplest:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

I also tried viewportScroller

```
this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
```

This does not work either:

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'top', 

    })

  ],
```

Does this something to do with the viewport meta, am I doing something wrong or should I change something there?

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601026/angular-2-scroll-to-top-on-route-change?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Hi Danish. Yes, Ive seen that post and it all works fine on the browser, but not on mobile phone's browsers (at least for me). The accepted solution below worked perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue before.

This worked for me

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfect. I wonder why the other solutions didn't work. Thanks.