# Angular 2 injectable AppSettings Class

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, appsettings

I'm using angular 2 inside of a ASP.NET Core application, but that isn't important for this issue.  Part of my current task is to get configuration values from the server into my angular application.

I have the settings flowing through to the point that I am writing one setting into my layout like so:

```
<script>
    var BASE_WEB_API_URL = '@appSettings.BaseUrls.Api';
</script>
```

And this is working, which I have verified by looking at the markup.  Now, what I want is to make an appsettings class that I can inject via DI into my services and components that need it.  Here is what I have so far:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppSettings {
    public BASE_WEB_API_URL: string = window['BASE_WEB_API_URL'];
}
```

Very simple and straight forward and it should allow me to inject my server variables.  However, I get an error when I try to use it.

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for AppSettings!

So, I thought my problem was that it wasn't listed in the imports in my app module.  So I added it only to get this error:

> Error: Unexpected value 'AppSettings' imported by the module 'AppModule'

So, googling this error lead me to a post saying it maybe needed to be in the bootstrap section, so I tried that next only to get a new error message.

> Error: No Directive annotation found on AppSettings

I'm very green to Angular 2, so these errors are throwing me off.  Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Don't put it into the module's `imports` metadata, put it into `providers`.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  However, now I have a "window is not defined" error happening inside my appsettings.ts

Comment: Compile error or runtime error?

Comment: This appears to be a compile time error.  I have searched around and found some posts on writing a window provider, but all solutions seem to error out.  [Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177221/angular2-how-to-inject-window-into-an-angular2-service)

Comment: Shouldn't need anything special to access the window. Don't know what to tell you.

Comment: I discovered the issue with window not defined.  You cannot use window if you are using server side pre-processing.  There is no window on the server side so it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put injectables into your module's `providers` metadata, not `imports`.