# Angular 2 AOT - Property 'window' does not exist on type

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-aot

In my Angular 2 application I provide the window object using what is described here: [Angular2 - How to inject window into an angular2 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177221/angular2-how-to-inject-window-into-an-angular2-service).

However the ngc compiler used for AOT returns several errors. First I had to change the way I provide the dependency (note the 'Window'):

```
@NgModule({        
  providers: [
    { provide: 'Window',  useValue: window }
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And in my component (note the type 'any'):

```
@Component({ ... })
export default class MyComponent {
    constructor (
        @Inject('Window') private window: any
    ) {}
...
```

However I still get the following error thrown by the ngc compiler in my module ngfactory:

> Property 'window' does not exist on type

Again everything is working fine with the tsc compiler.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I fixed my issue by following exactly what is described here: http://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-get-window-ref/

Answer (score 1):

The following, simple solution did the trick for me:

Under "**@NgModule**", in "**providers**" section:

```
{provide: 'window', useFactory: getWindow }
```

Make sure to export the "getWindow" method:

```
export function getWindow() { return window; }
```

Source - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14050