# Angular testing Service method with window.location.replace

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, window.location

In my Angular 4 application, I need to test a method of a Service which at some point it calls a private method of the same service having:

`window.location.replace(url);`

**When the test reach that line, the karma-runner browser gets redirected to the `url` which of course is not what I want.**

If I try to spy it, I get:

`Error: <spyOn> : replace is not declared writable or has no setter`

How can I correctly test my method?

Comment: I'd move any reference to the window into a separate service, which should be trivial and which you can then mock elsewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - How to inject window into an angular2 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177221/angular2-how-to-inject-window-into-an-angular2-service)

Answer (score 2):

`location` object is [read-only property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location), and its properties are read-only as well.

The best test-friendly strategy  is to not use native objects directly but via DI, because testabiliry is one of main benefits of DI.

`document` already has `DOCUMENT` [provider abstraction](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DOCUMENT), the same can be done for `window` entirely, similarly to AngularJS `$window` service:

```
const WINDOW = new InjectionToken('window');
function getWindow() {
  return window;
}

...
{ provide: WINDOW, useFactory: getWindow }
...

...
constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) public window) {
  this.window.location.replace(...);
}
...
```

In this setup `WINDOW` provider can be stubbed in tests, and globals can be thoroughly tested.

Alternatively, providers can be created for each global in use.