# angular4 document and window are undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, .net-core

I am using dot net core with angular 4 and webpack config.

When I am trying to get the window or document in a component or service, I am getting this error:

> ReferenceError: document is not defined
>
> ReferenceError: window is not defined

Here are the errors i am getting:

```html
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
      ERROR { ReferenceError: window is not defined
          at _window (C:\gitRepose\AngularCore\FM\FMWebApp\FootballWebApp\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:30801:12)
```

```html
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred: window is not defined
      ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at _window (C:\gitRepose\AngularCore\FM\FMWebApp\FootballWebApp\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:30801:12)
```

I am still new to the webpack stuff, anyone know how i can fix this?
I need the window to handle when a window is resizing.

EDIT...

I managed to get this fixed by removing the pre render from the index.cshtml

i changed it from this:

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

to this:

```
<app>Loading...</app>
```

but now obviously pre rendering on server side won't be happening :/ thus it will slow the app boot up time, any ideas how I can fix this without loosing server side pre rendering?

Comment: Did you use the [Microsoft ASP.NET Core SPA Templates](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) to generate your project?

Comment: yes i used them, why?

Answer (score 8):

If you're using server-side rendering, you should remove all code using `window` or `document` that run in node because node doesn't have these variables (node only have `global`).

If you still want to use `window` or `document` in node env, you can try to use jsdom (https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

Comment: Do you know how I should set JSDOM up in my webpack configuration? or do you have any helpful link?

Comment: You don't need to add jsdom to webpack's config. You just need to require it in your node: https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

Comment: @fattikus You can read its docs because of how to use is depend on what you want. But in my optional, you don't need to use `window` in server-side rendering

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use AOT, use dependency injection to mount window into your components. In short, write a service that can provide the window object:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

function getWindow (): any {
    return window;
}

@Injectable()
export class WindowRefService {
    get nativeWindow (): any {
        return getWindow();
    }
}
```

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37176929/2346893).

Comment: the code that requires windows is in another library /npm package not in my code.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a quick fix : 
put this code at the top of your typescript file :

```
 declare var window;
 declare var document;
```

---

But if you wanna do it properly :

```
 import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 export const WINDOW           = new InjectionToken( 'WINDOW' );

 @Component()
 export class YourComponent{
          constructor(
              @Inject( WINDOW ) private window,
              @Inject( DOCUMENT ) private document){}
```

inside your module :

```
providers       : [
    {
        provide  : WINDOW,
        useValue : window
    }
],
```

This way you can override window and document in your tests and anywhere else.

Comment: no, not my code requires window and document, a code installed from an npm package

Comment: the problem is the pre rendering of webpack / i am using dot net core

Answer (score 3):

wrap your code which depends on window like below

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // your client-only logic here like below
    alert(window.innerWidth);
}
```

Comment: this is not a solution since I need to import UI libraries which use the document/window

Comment: you can import your ui libraries in the client side

Answer (score 3):

Well i'm using angular 4 application and inject the window object using:

In Component `constructor( @Inject('Window') private window: Window) { }`

and In module: `providers: [{ provide: 'Window', useValue: window }]`

and then in the component function i used it like: `this.window`

Comment: the code that requires windows is in another library /npm package not in my code.

Answer (score 3):

In Server Side JavaScript is running in Node Environment which does not have window or document object. Window &  Document object works when your javascript code executes in Browser Environment. So make sure window or document object related code does not execute on Server Side

You may use [node-jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jsdom) (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jsdom) if you really need to use window or document object. Just install

```
$ npm install node-jsdom
```

[Here](https://github.com/darrylwest/node-jsdom)  (https://github.com/darrylwest/node-jsdom) you will get help on node-jsdom

Answer (score 1):

Place your window. related code inside componentDidMount function.

Comment: componentDidMount  is something related to react? or webpack

Comment: He is using angular not react!

Comment: In angular4, another hook can be used: ngAfterViewChecked()

Comment: @user8335505 however when using libraries (ui libraries, like ngx data grid or ng zorro) which make use of document and window, how am i going to do this? its still not a solution

Answer (score 0):

In **Index.html** or **Index.cshtml**

Change From

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

To

```
<app asp-ng2-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

If you are using angular4 in aspnetcore, It should work fine