# How to call a function when scroll up or down in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, scroll, angular6

How we can call a function when a user scrolls up or down in angular 6?

I'm willing to create something like [fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) in angular 6. First, I tried to solve this problem with angular animations but no success. Now, I'm making use of [ngx-scroll-to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to) for scrolling to current slide. So, consider I know how to write `scroll_to_bottom_slide()` and `scroll_to_top_slide functions()` in this example, But I don't know how to write the proper events.

example :

```
scrollDown(){
    scroll_to_bottom_slide();
}
scrollUp(){
    scroll_to_top_slide();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `@HostListener`
source: https://brianflove.com/2016/10/10/angular-2-window-scroll-event-using-hostlistener

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the window...

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', ...some function...);
```

You could create a DI for the window just like here:

[Angular2 - How to inject window into an angular2 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177221/angular2-how-to-inject-window-into-an-angular2-service)