# Angular - Testing window.href.location

Tags: angular, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I am doing unit tests for my Angular app. I have a service that calls `window.location.href = <URL>`

When I try testing the code it returns an error:

```
Chrome 117.0.0.0 (Windows 10) ERROR
  Some of your tests did a full page reload!
```

But this is expected behavior, I want the page to change.

I also tried some of the solutions pointed here in other questions, such as creating a spy, as mentioned here [other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69537614/angular-unit-testing-window-location-href), but they return this other error:

```
Chrome 117.0.0.0 (Windows 10) ERROR                                                                     
  Disconnected , because no message in 30000 ms.
```

I even tried to increase the time for timeout on karma.conf, but does not help.

Has anyone encountered this and been able to solve, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Angular provides a `Location` service that can be injected and mocked. Better to use that rather than access `window.location` directly. https://angular.io/api/common/Location