# Angular window.parent.postMessage jasmine unit testing

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How can I test this method with postMessage

```js
navigateTo = (): void => {
    window.parent.postMessage('NESTED_NAVIGATION', 'target_origin');
}
```

I want to check if the postMessage event is fired when I call the `navigateTo` method

I tried this but didn't work

```js
it('should post message on click', async () => {
   spyOn(component, 'navigateTo');
   let postMessageSpy = spyOn(window.parent, 'postMessage');
   component.navigateTo();
   expect(postMessageSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried injecting the window so that you can spy on it instead? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52620181/973651 (there's a few options in the answers)

Comment: When you apply `spyOn` on a method (`navigateTo`) without calling `.and.callThrough()`, that method becomes a stub meaning its actual content is not being invoked in your example. Other than that, you do not need at all to spy on `navigateTo`, you need it to be invoked as is (after all, that is the method you want to test).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are testing the `component.navigateTo()` method, so you should NOT use `spyOn` for it. Otherwise, the `window.parent.postMessage()` will never be called. You should use `spyOn` for `window.parent.postMessage()` method.

From the [Default Spy Strategy](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/default_spy_strategy)

> Normally, the default strategy is `.and.stub()`, which returns `undefined` if the spy is called.

So the correct test code should be:

`example.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {}
  navigateTo = (): void => {
    window.parent.postMessage('NESTED_NAVIGATION', 'target_origin');
  };
}
```

`example.component.test.ts`:

```
import { ExampleComponent } from './example.component';

describe('70440045', () => {
  it('should post message on click', async () => {
    const component = new ExampleComponent();
    let postMessageSpy: jasmine.Spy<(message: any, targetOrigin: string, transfer?: Transferable[]) => void> = spyOn(
      window.parent,
      'postMessage',
    );
    component.navigateTo();
    expect(postMessageSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('NESTED_NAVIGATION', 'target_origin');
  });
});
```

We specify the overload signature of `postMessage` to avoid TS type errors.

Test result:

```sh
Chrome Headless 95.0.4638.69 (Mac OS 10.15.7): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.008 secs / 0.004 secs)
TOTAL: 1 SUCCESS

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 94.12% ( 16/17 )
Branches     : 100% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : 62.5% ( 5/8 )
Lines        : 100% ( 13/13 )
================================================================================
```

package version:

```json
"@angular/core": "~11.0.3",
"@angular/cli": "~11.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma": "~5.1.0",
"jasmine-core": "^3.10.1"
```