# Read and edit global javascript variable from Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, web

I have an angular app where in my index.html i have a variable inside a  tag, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let global = 5;
</script>
```

I need to read and edit the value of this variable, inside an angular component, but I do not know how to do it.

I saw that it is possible to read the value if you create the variable inside the "window" object  of javascript (window.global = 5) and then use it in angular component, but i think it would not work for me because i need that variable to be outside, as specified above.

Is it possible? Any ideas?

Comment: if you change the `let` to `var` then you can indeed reference it from anywhere - including Angular components - as `window.global`. But really, think of any alternative to using global variables.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Finally I used your idea and it worked. I know it is not the best idea to use global variables but in this case I have no choice :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used an aproximation of [@robin-zigmond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8475054/robin-zigmond) answer. I changed let to var in the script tag and in my angular component I access the variable using:

```
window["global"]
```

I can edit the value inside a component using, for example:

```
window["global"] = 6
```

[image]

Moreover, I tried [@mbojko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7194268/mbojko) answer and it worked too.

Answer (score 4):

The keyword `declare` to the rescue: first, declare your global with `var` (`let` doesn't work)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var someVar = 5;
</script>
```

and access it in, say, Angular component:

```
declare var someVar;
// ...
    this.foo = someVar;
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zjpnzq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the window varaible to the scope in your controller.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>window.HELLO_MSG = 'Hello,';</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{ wlcmMsg + " " + firstName + " " + lastName }}
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.wlcmMsg = window.HELLO_MSG;
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Or you can inject the whole window object like here:
[How to inject window into a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177221/how-to-inject-window-into-a-service)

Comment: We're talking Angular, not AngularJS.